# Duplicating & modifying rows in pandas based on columns condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As part of a classification problem, I work on a DataFrame containing **multiple label columns**.

My dataframe is of this form :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 1],
                   ['b', 1, 0],
                   ['c', 0, 0]] , columns=['col1', 'label1', 'label2'])

>>>   col1  label1  label2
    0    a       1       1
    1    b       1       0
    2    c       0       0
```

As **I do not want to have more than one true label** per row, I want to duplicate only those rows and regularize this condition as follows :

```
>>>   col1  label1  label2
    0    a       1       0 # Modified original row
    1    a       0       1 # Duplicated & modified row
    2    b       1       0
    3    c       0       0
```

With only the row of value "a" being duplicated / regularized

At the moment I do that in a for loop, replicating the rows in a second DataFrame, appending it and dropping all the "invalid" rows.

Would there be a more clean/efficient way to do that ?

Comment: All the answers should not be upvoted. Only mine and Dmitry K.'s are correct. The others do not work on other larger datasets. Check this dataframe with the other answers and you will see. `n=100
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.arange(n), 'label1':np.random.randint(0, 2, n), 'label2':np.random.randint(0, 2, n)})`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> cols = [x for x in df.columns is x != 'col1']
>>> res = pd.concat([df[['col1', x]] for x in cols])
>>> res = res.drop_duplicates()
>>> res.fillna(0, inplace=True)
>>> res.sort_values(by='col1', inplace=True)
>>> res.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
>>> res
  col1  label1  label2
0    a       1       0
1    a       0       1
2    b       1       0
3    b       0       0
4    c       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `df.iterrows()` doing as follows :

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1]+row[2]==2:
        df = pd.concat((df, pd.DataFrame({'col1':[row[0]], 'label1':[0], 'label2':[1]})),ignore_index=True)
        df = pd.concat((df, pd.DataFrame({'col1':[row[0]], 'label1':[1], 'label2':[0]})), ignore_index=True)
        df.drop(index, inplace=True)
```

Result :

```
  col1  label1  label2
1    b       1       0
2    c       0       0
3    a       0       1
4    a       1       0
```

Then you can sort regarding values on `col1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat intuitive way of thinking about the problem. First, filter for just the rows that have label both equal to 1. Make two new dataframes by replacing each column by zero, once each.

Then concatenate the original dataframe without both rows equal to one to the two new dataframes created.

```
mask_ones = (df['label1'] == 1) & (df['label2'] == 1)
df_ones = df[mask_ones]
df_not_ones = df[~mask_ones]
df_final = pd.concat([df_not_ones, 
                      df_ones.replace({'label2':{1:0}}),
                      df_ones.replace({'label1':{1:0}})]).sort_values('col1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Split into 2 df - unique and duplicates. 
For duplicates took col1 + label1 columns and concat with col1 + label2 and fill nan with 0.
Concat unique and duplicates df into one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 1],
                   ['b', 1, 0],
                   ['c', 0, 0]], columns=['col1', 'label1', 'label2'])

mask = (df['label1'] == 1) & (df['label2'] == 1)
df_dup, df_uq = df[mask], df[~mask]
df_dup = pd.concat([df_dup[['col1', x]] for x in df_dup.columns if x != 'col1']).fillna(0)
df = pd.concat([df_dup, df_uq], ignore_index=True)
print(df)

  col1  label1  label2
0    a     1.0     0.0
1    a     0.0     1.0
2    b     1.0     0.0
3    c     0.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 1],
                   ['b', 1, 0],
                   ['c', 0, 0]] , columns=['col1', 'label1', 'label2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2["col1"] = df["col1"]
df2["label2"] = df["label2"]
df.drop(labels="label2", axis=1, inplace=True)
result = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
result.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
result.sort_values(by="col1")
```

Result:

```
  col1   label1   label2
0    a 1.000000 0.000000
3    a 0.000000 1.000000
1    b 1.000000 0.000000
4    b 0.000000 0.000000
2    c 0.000000 0.000000
5    c 0.000000 0.000000
```

Finally, you could drop duplicates

```
result.drop_duplicates()
```